# Declaring uninitialized variable which is initialized within a nested scope

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following C++ snippet

```
double exetime = 0;  
SVDRec R;
{
  timer<double> dummy{exetime};
  R = svdLAS2();
}
std::cout << exetime << std::endl;
```

where the constructor of `timer` records the time the scoping block was entered, and its destructor (which is called when the block is leaved) computes the passed time and stores it in `exetime`. `R` is only initialized inside the block, and it does not have a default constructor, so the code doesn't compile for this reason. But I do not want to initialize `R` to some dummy value.

This, too, doesn't compile:

```
double exetime = 0;  
SVDRec &&tmpR;
{
  timer<double> dummy{exetime};
  tmpR = svdLAS2();
}
SVDRec R = tmpR;
std::cout << exetime << std::endl;
```

I know I could use a pointer but I do not want to use dynamic allocation nor std::unique_ptr. Is there is anyway to achieve this?

Comment: I would change this timing thing to be a function instead.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes So I'd use two calls, one at the beginning and another at the end? This is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: No. You would have the same thing: a function defines a scope just as well. But a function can return a value. A lambda works nicely for that, as Eddie suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
double exetime = 0;  
SVDRec R = [&exetime]()
{
  timer<double> dummy{exetime};
  return svdLAS2();
}();

std::cout << exetime << std::endl;
```